# Exploding a string , returning an array removing one string for each key

Tags: php, php-7

Let's say we have the string **The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog**

I want an array returned with the following ( removing one word each time ).

```
array:9 [▼
  0 => "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
  1 => "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
  2 => "brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"
  3 => "fox jumps over the lazy dog"
  4 => "jumps over the lazy dog"
  5 => "over the lazy dog"
  6 => "the lazy dog"
  7 => "lazy dog"
  8 => "dog"
]
```

I quickly whipped up the following function that does this.

```
function wordsToArr($str)
    {

           $words =[];
           $ex_str =explode(' ',$str);


           foreach($ex_str as $k=>$v){

              $words[] =implode(' ',$ex_str);

              unset($ex_str[$k]);
            }

           return $words;
    }
```

Now my question :  is there a faster way , performance wise to do this ?

**UPDATE**   As requested I performed a benchmark.  Also tried it with the following function :

```
function wordsToArr2($str)
    {

        $words =[$str];
        while($pos =strpos ( $str , ' ')){

            $str=substr($str,($pos+1));
            $words[] =$str;
        }

        return $words;

    }
```

Used this script to benchmark it : https://gist.github.com/blongden/2352583

Results :

```
Explode (wordsToArr) string run: 317,505/sec
strpos/substr (wordsToArr2) run: 542,725/sec
```

My question remains , is there any other function to make this even faster ?

Comment: Have you benchmarked this?

Comment: you could also work with a strpos and substr. Then benchmark both ways.

Comment: does the order of the final array matter?

Comment: @fyrye : yes , it must be from full string to single word. thanks for taking the time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `strpos` and `substr` may be the most consistently performant.

An alternative however, since you already have a list of words, instead of removing each word, you can use concatenation instead.  Reducing the number of function calls per iteration.

### Example: https://3v4l.org/j5YMm

```
$str = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog';
$base = array_reverse(explode(' ', $str));
$words = [$placeholder = array_shift($base)];
foreach($base as $word) {
    $words[] = $placeholder = $word . ' ' . $placeholder;
}
$words = array_reverse($words);
print_r($words);
```

### Results

*numbers are very inconsistent on 3v4l - benchmark on your own server and PHP version*

**PHP 5.6.38**

```
implode 100 times in: 0.00047302/sec
strpos 100 times in:  0.00035501/sec
concat 100 times in:  0.00034595/sec
```

**Returns**

```
Array
(
    [0] => The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    [1] => quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    [2] => brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    [3] => fox jumps over the lazy dog
    [4] => jumps over the lazy dog
    [5] => over the lazy dog
    [6] => the lazy dog
    [7] => lazy dog
    [8] => dog
)
```

---

**Note**
There are very many ways to implement the concatenation as well.

You can replace `array_shift` which requires re-indexing of the array with `array_pop`, reducing opcode complexity slightly.

```
$base = explode(' ', $str);
$words = [$placeholder = array_pop($base)];
$base = array_reverse($base);
```

You can also use a condition on the key within the `foreach`, to determine if concatenation should be used, with little performance loss.

```
$base = array_reverse(explode(' ', $str));
$s = '';
foreach ($base as $i => $w) {
    $words[] = $s = ($i === 0 ? $w : $w . ' ' . $s);
}
```

---

**Updated**

As another alternative to reduce the number of opcode calls, you can use `for count()` using `$i--` to process the array in reverse. 
With an option of replacing `$l = count($base) - 1;` with `end($base); $l = key($base);`, or using `array_key_last` for PHP 7.3

### Example https://3v4l.org/VfJku

```
$base = explode(' ', $str);
$l = count($base)-1;
$words = [$placeholder = $base[$l--]];
for ($i=$l; $i>=0;$i--) {
    $words[] = $placeholder =   $base[$i] . ' ' . $placeholder;
}
$words = array_reverse($words);
print_r($words);
```

**PHP 5.6.38**

```
strpos 100 times in: 0.00043607/sec
concat 100 times in: 0.00044894/sec
end/key 100 times in: 0.00037289/sec
count-- 100 times in: 0.00036097/sec
```

Comment: _"very inconsistent"_ = very true. I get `strpos 100 times in: 0.00016689/sec` on your 3v4l example. That's less then half of what you cited. Kinda the same on phptester.net. But always strpos the way fastest.

Comment: @Jeff inconsistency is to be expected on a shared resource site like 3v4l and phptester, that are used by a very large number of people, making benchmarks on them fairly useless. When used on a site configured for production, the results will be more consistent. The number i sited was to demonstrate the worst-case benchmark. Which for PHP 5.6, does not have the same opcode enhancements as 7.0+.

Comment: Thanks mate, benchmarked them on a simple home server with php 7.1 and got the following results :                                                                  
 WordsArr1: 312,799/sec
wordsArr2: 413,368/sec
wordsArr3: 442,490/sec
wordsArr4: 432,125/sec
wordsArr5: 193,221/sec  ,   your array reverse seems to do well on php 7.